# Convert Rich text image string to image c# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox

I am trying to take an embeded image in a rich text box and convert it to an actual Image (.jpg, .png) doesnt really matter what format.

Sofar i have managed to get just the image as a string from my rich text box.

I am stuck on converting the rich text string (imageData from code below) to an actual image.

```
string imageData = ExtractImg(rtfText);

string ExtractImg(string s)
{
    int startIndex = s.IndexOf("{\\pict\\");
    int endIndex = s.IndexOf("}", startIndex);
    return s.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex + 1) - startIndex);
}
```

Comment: Here's the spec: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading49

Comment: Thanks, thats some really useful information. Unfortunatly it doesnt help with my problem of converting the rtf string to an image.

Comment: Well, you'll have to parse the data from the `\pict` string and create a bitmap from it. Maybe there's some library that already does that.

Comment: Check out NRtfTree - http://nrtftree.sourceforge.net/examples.html#example17